# Popup window in .NET MVC

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, popupwindow, tempdata

I have a requirement of populating a new window (With no menus, no address bar) using the existing data that I have on the page.
I am using a java script function for this purpose.

```
function popup() {
        window.open("../AcknowledgeStatements/OutStandingAckInPdf", '', 'scrollbars=yes,width=740,height=600,resizable=yes');
    }


<input name="cmdButton" id="cmdPrint" type="button" class="button" value="Print"  onclick="popup()"/>
```

How do I pass my Model and TempData/ViewData in this page to the popup window?
Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

Well since you don't want to see Menus or the Address bar, i would also add menubar=no,location=no to your optional specs arguments.  You can find a full list of options [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Now, as far as passing data to your new window: window.open, doesn't have any way of doing this.  What you would have to do is pass any data you want displayed on the popup to the server as GET arguments

```
function popup() {
    window.open("../AcknowledgeStatements/OutStandingAckInPdf?SomeParam=SomeValue&SecondParam=SomeValue", '', 'scrollbars=yes,width=740,height=600,resizable=yes');
}
```

then pass down your data in the view.  But remmeber there are limitations on this as GET paramaters can limited in length to maximum length of a web address.  This i think is 1024 char, but don't quote me on that.

Anyways, further more.  Why do you need this data to show up in a popup.  Popup windows a relic of the past that usually just annoy users.  Most modern browsers tend to block popups and require a user to explicitly allows the popup to be displayed.   You can save yourself a round trip to the server if you pre-include a [template](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/05/07/jquery-templates-and-data-linking-and-microsoft-contributing-to-jquery.aspx) (good explanation behind what you can do with it) in your original html and then have it display as a [dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).  IMHO this is a much more friendly option then popups.